# How to stop meeting being stripped on forward (EWS)

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am using C# with the Exchange Web Service (EWS).

I have meetings that I need to forward and whenever I do they get stripped, but only from some accounts and not others. The link for the meeting is still there but it is not being recognised by the online Outlook as a meeting item, nor by Teams which is connected to the account.

This even happens if I manually forward, but again only if I forward emails that are from some accounts - some other accounts are fine!

I'm using this on incoming emails:

```
 var fwdEmailArr = new EmailAddress[1];
 fwdEmailArr [0] = fwdEmail;
 MeetingRequest appointment = MeetingRequest.Bind(service, email.Id);
 appointment.Forward("", fwdEmailArr);
```

This is the same issue if I use the email.forward as well, etc.

However, if I create a new appointment and send it, it doesn't get stripped - this is with the same addresses.

```
Appointment appt = new Appointment(service);
appt.Subject = email.Subject;
appt.Body = appointment.Body;
appt.Start = appointment.Start;
appt.End = appointment.End;
appt.Location = appointment.Location;
appt.RequiredAttendees.Add(fwdEmail);
foreach (var reqAtt in appt.RequiredAttendees)
{
    appt.RequiredAttendees.Add(reqAtt);
}

foreach (var reqAtt in appt.OptionalAttendees)
{
    appt.OptionalAttendees.Add(reqAtt);
}
appt.RequiredAttendees.Add(appointment.From.Address);
appt.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
```

So, I could do this but it means that they are no longer the same meeting and declining the original wont decline this. Unless there's a way I can connect the meetings or something?

Any ideas how I can stop the meeting being stripped?

Or alternatively just add another recipient to the current meeting, that will show on their calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone comes here with a similar issue, it turns out that, first of all you need to make sure you define the correct server version on the service declaration:

```
service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2016){}
```

In addition, for some reason some images when attached to the forwarded email for some reason confuse EWS and make it think there's no meeting. I got around this by scanning the MIME content and just extracting the calendar block and deleting all other attachments.

This has been working flawlessly for about 5 months.